# What is the opposite of a greeting?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you need to begin conversation with some one normally people begin the conversation with a greeting such as hello, good day/morning/evening, sup, what's going on and so on and so forth. All of wich are are considered greetings. But what do you call the words, phrases, or sentences used for say goodbye to someone. Such as well goodbye, see ya, catch you later and etc. Would they be called farewells or is there another word for them.

Comment: Uh, "farewell" or "bidding farewell", or "goodbye".

Comment: This can be looked up in a thesaurus, but you're going to have be more specific if you're looking for something in particular.

Comment: "We said our goodbyes" would be idiomatic (if a hair formal) in the US.  But there are many other options.